# Google analytics updated to track 2 IDs, not working as expected

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, tracking, multiple-instances

We use to have a regular tracking, like this:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'www.websitename.com');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

The thing is that due a google adwords campaing, in the marketing department needed to track the visits in two different google analytics ID's, and they gave us this code (wich I am not familiar with)

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'www.websitename.com');
ga('create', 'UA-YYYYYYY-46', 'auto', {'allowLinker': true});
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['otherwebsitename.com'] );
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

The problem is that they are saying that google analytics it's not tracking properly,

so the question is, Do you see anything wrong in the code i posted?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is creating  two trackers but you sent data only to one of them. You need to give a name to one of the trackers and make one additional send pageview-call to that name.

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'www.websitename.com');
ga('create', 'UA-YYYYYYY-46', 'auto', {'name': 'newTracker', 'allowLinker': true}); // NAME SET HERE !
ga('require', 'linker');
ga('linker:autoLink', ['otherwebsitename.com'] );
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('newTracker.send', 'pageview'); // NAME CALLED HERE !
```

Ask them if they are sure they need the crossdomain tracking (the bits that have "link" or "linker" in them), else the code can be much simplified (and since they seem not to understand how the code works they might have included those lines erroneously).

Comment: Thank you, We are testing your suggested modifications and they look much happier! let you know, thanks again!